# Fuzzy search for name

Tags: java, solr, fuzzy-search

I have a csv file having 4 column as 'student_name', 'father_name', 'date_of_passing','admission_number'. There are 500 milion rows in csv file. Now  i have to do fuzzy search on two columns (student_
name,father_name') and retrieve other columns(date_of_passing, admission_number) as well, So input will be student_name, father_name.

I have spent hours looking for addressing this problem on google and reached on apache solr(underhood-lucene) for fuzzy matching.I understand that Apache Solr is an Open-source REST-API based Enterprise Real-time Search engine. It is a high-performance and full-featured text search engine library.Lucene offers powerful features like scalable and high-performance indexing of the documents.
I followed link

```
https://mkyong.com/solr/apache-solr-hello-world-example/
```

After installation I accessed link

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/bigboxstore/select?indent=on&q=name:'alaistiar~'&wt=json
```

which showed me results,on the basis of input i should consider complete result set or should i restrict the result according to score or Is there any other way to do this? i understand that  score is a relative thing determined by Lucene based on index statistics.

For fuzzy search in apache solr i have following query

1 Following url is right way to implement fuzzy seach in application using Apache solr or not?
http://localhost:8983/solr/bigboxstore/select?indent=on&q=name:'alaistiar~'&wt=json

2. For fuzzy search,In apache solr should i consider complete result set result returned from point 1 or should i restrict the result according to score or Is there any other way to do this?
3. How can I find out similarity criteria (90%above) for student_name and father_name separately?

Comment: Stackoverflow is better suited for specific problems encountered while running a program, and how to fix the code. You may not get good suggestions for such questions here.

Comment: 1: sure, `name:alistiar~1` would give you anything within one edit-distance of alistiar. 2: That depends on your requirement; is this what you want? 3: What does 90% mean?

Comment: @MatsLindh Thankx for reply! 3. I want to do following two things for name column : a. spell-check b. out of order components ( Mitchel Marsh and Marsh Mitchel)

Comment: https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_9/spell-checking.html - `name:"Mitchel Marsh"~1`